# How do I replace every file in a folder with 0kb files?

Tags: file, batch-file, replace

I'm trying to write a batch file to replace every file in a folder with a 0kb copy of the exact same name, the original files may be deleted. Need to do this for hundreds of files but I haven't found a decent way to do it, is it even possible in Batch? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

in fact, it is quite easy:

```
for %%i in (*) do copy /y nul "%%i"
```

`copy /Y` overwrites without warning, writes nothing (`nul`) to the file, overwriting the old one.

If you use this on cmd-line (not in a batch file), write `%i` instead of `%%i` (both)

Put the second `%%i` in quotes to process files with spaces in the filename correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Is it safe to run this, so it only affects this one folder that I run it in? Wouldn't want it to spread to others! :D

Comment: safe? well, depends on its usage ;) It will empty all files in the current folder (it won't go into subfolders or other folders). Take care to use the correct folder. For testing, put a `echo` in front of the `copy...`, so it will tell you what it would do.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to hear!
It works perfectly, thank you :)